# OpenDaylight add more listening port

Tags: port, opendaylight, openflow

In `OpenDaylight`, `tcp` listening port default set as `6653`, `6633`.
But I want to use more ports (e.g. `6634`, `6635`).

Where should I config them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add more openflow ports to listen on, but **maybe** you can
change 6633 and/or 6653 to a different port if that helps.

I'm not sure it works, but you can try to search for and edit these two files
to do that:

```
default-openflow-connection-config.xml
legacy-openflow-connection-config.xml
```

You could also try port redirection with iptables to achieve something simliar.
I've never done that either, but seems like it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try something similar.
By the way, do you know how controller send multipart request to connected device parallel?
Because this question arise from I want to use more bossthread to enhance my openflowplugin processing time, and I find 6633/6653 port use different bossthread to processing.
Thanks!